# Host name may not be empty

Tags: java, android, kotlin, release, android-studio-4.0

After upgrading my Android Studio, I got this error whenever I wanted to generate a signed Apk (without any detail of where the problem is). There was no problem when I just built Apk.

```
The Host name may not be empty
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Check your Gradle scripts root. If there is this file: **gradle.properties (Global Properties)**, check that values are correct.

In my case, **I removed all these properties** and my problem solved

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=
systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
systemProp.https.proxyHost=
systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
```

Comment: @RaviParmar maybe this error occurs in different cases.  For my problem, It worked

Comment: File location: ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

Comment: I have same issue but this solution not working for me

Comment: for windows it was located in C:\Users\{username}\.gradle\ folder

Comment: To be more specific it is system level `./gradle` dir having `gradle.properties` file. e.g for mac path is `/Users/[username]/.gradle/gradle.properties`

Answer (score 13):

It may be problem with uploadMappingFile

Set the `firebaseCrashlytics.enableMappingFileUpload` Gradle extension property to true in your app-level build.gradle file.

```
// To enable Crashlytics mapping file upload for specific product flavors:
  flavorDimensions "environment"
  productFlavors {
    staging {
      dimension "environment"
      ...
      firebaseCrashlytics {
        mappingFileUploadEnabled false
      }
    }
    prod {
      dimension "environment"
      ...
      firebaseCrashlytics {
        mappingFileUploadEnabled true
      }
    }
  }
```

for more details visit [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android)

Comment: This helped me. Many other suggestions did not, but this one did. Thank you

Answer (score 10):

Yep, problem started at AS 4.0 up..  Here are the **clearer fixes**...  (Cos Some may think the *"**gradle.properties**"* file being talked about here is what is in the AS project instead of the global one.

Delete the following lines from the ***"gradle.propeties"*** file on your PC gradle installation location

> systemProp.http.proxyHost= systemProp.https.proxyHost=
> systemProp.https.proxyPort=80 systemProp.http.proxyPort=80

as seen in n my picture below here is a **typical file location** of this ***gradle.propeties*** file
[image]

[image]

***Now click rebuild in your project and VIOLA...  Problem solved***

Comment: Thank you for adding pictures. It definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, I fixed that issue by applying Proguard rules,

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android

In project proguard-rules.pro

-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception

Gradle

firebaseCrashlytics {
mappingFileUploadEnabled true
}

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused due to empty xml file in your res directory. Open the res directory in explorer/finder sort all the xml according to their size. Find the xml with 0kb / empty xml and delete it. Now you can create your signed bundled apk.

Answer (score 0):

When I removed all the http.proxyPort then it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was WebDriver requiring a fully qualified url. Switching from `localhost:9000` to `http://localhost:9000/` did the trick for me (hopefully helps others too).

This is because the WebDriver method `void get(String url);` was being called and giving the error:

`The Host name may not be empty`

The java doc for the param states:

`Params: url – The URL to load. Must be a fully qualified URL`

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users check your `gradle.properties` file located at `/Users/[username]/.gradle/gradle.properties` and remove the following properties

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=
systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
systemProp.https.proxyHost=
systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
```