# host name may not be empty after upgrade Android Studio to 2021.1.1

Tags: android

After upgrading my Android Studio to 2021.1.1, I got this error when try to generate a signed Apk. There was no problem when I debugging the application emulator or remote on true phone.

I've tried to follow this patch:
**1-insert the firebaseCrashlytics mappingFileUploadEnabled true**

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin.
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }




compileSdkVersion 32
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com_pro.bandweb.mycpstore"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 32
        // versionCode 1
        //versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        if (!localProperties['base64EncodedPublicKey']) {
            logger.warn('base64EncodedPublicKey must be set for signature verification. ' +
                    'You can add it to local.properties once you have gotten it from Play. ' +
                    'Example: base64EncodedPublicKey=[key value]')
        }
        buildConfigField("String", "BASE64_ENCODED_PUBLIC_KEY", "\"" + localProperties['base64EncodedPublicKey'] + "\"")

    }
buildTypes {
            release {
                // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only
                // your project's release build type.
                minifyEnabled true
                // Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the
                // Android Gradle plugin.
                shrinkResources true
    
                // Includes the default ProGuard rules files that are packaged with
                // the Android Gradle plugin. To learn more, go to the section about
                // R8 configuration files.
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                debuggable false
                // To enable Crashlytics mapping file upload for specific product flavors:
                firebaseCrashlytics {
                    mappingFileUploadEnabled true
                }
            }
            debug {
                debuggable true
                //applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
                signingConfig signingConfigs.config
                // To enable Crashlytics mapping file upload for specific product flavors:
                firebaseCrashlytics {
                    mappingFileUploadEnabled false
                }
            }
        }
```

**2- delete this line in this file: gradle.properties (Global Properties)**([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62128323/4567295))

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=
systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
systemProp.https.proxyHost=
systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
```

but nothing of this tricks had success
the error are always the same:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease'.
> Host name may not be empty
```

**UPDATE**
*The only workaround that I found is to set to false under
release but I didn't want to give up to Crashlytics*

```
firebaseCrashlytics {
                mappingFileUploadEnabled false
            }
```

Comment: I've experience the same problem. It only happened when an android device is connected to your computer. Try unplugged the device before building apk.

Comment: sorry, but no device connected during building the apk...

Comment: I have the exact same problem with Android Studio 2022.1.1 Patch 2 and firebase-crashlytics-ktx:18.3.5